# The use of 'there' in questions

Tags: questions

I'm an English teacher in Belgium and would like to know the following...
I gave my students the sentence 'There were a lot of people **in the shop**.' I asked my students to make a good question to get **in the shop** as the answer.
-> 'Where were there a lot of people?' A lot of my students wrote -> 'Where were a lot of people?'  Is that also correct?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's as grammatical, and makes as much sense as, the sentence you expected. But that's a very odd thing to ask a sentence about, and since (b) the point of _There_-Insertion is to fill the initial subject position with a dummy subject, while moving the real intransitive subject to the end, and (b) _Wh_-Question Formation already fills the initial position, they probly figured there was no reason for an initial _there_ and unwound the transformation.

Comment: @JohnLawler Or, if my epxerience of learners who've been taught the existential construction is anything to go by, they haven't fully got that *there* has no meaning and is not locative in any way. Most students don't get this, even if it's pointed out to them. I deeply suspect, that taking *there* to be a locative word, they replaced it with a locative question word, *where* to form their question.

Comment: It still has a pretty common locative sense, [judging by the verbs it occurs with](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/there-levin.pdf), but certainly the pure existential idiom requires no location beyond a set to belong to.

Comment: To the OP: You might have pointed out for them (even in the introduction to the test)  the difference between '__There were__ a lot of people in the shop.' and '__There in the shop__ were a lot of people .'

Comment: OP: you may consider this good example of usage: https://books.google.ca/books?id=ytzk4BCJVcgC&pg=PA75&dq=%22Where+were+there%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xBYgVbrkDMrHsAWL8YGYDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Where%20were%20there%22&f=false

Comment: Your students are quite correct. Looking in Google books for *"where is there a"*, nearly all the hits are rhetorical questions.

Comment: @Marius Hanku: your example "There in the shop were lots of people.", though grammatcally correct, would be more understandable with commas: "There, in the shop, were lots of people."  That makes is clear that "there" is locative (if you meant it as a dummy "there", best to leave it out; the sentence stands without it: "In the shop were a lot of people."

Comment: [*I saw a mouse -- where? There on the stair
Where on the stair? Right there
A little mouse with clogs on -- well, I declare
Going clip-clippety-clop on the stair - oh yeah*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fg7w49UnGA)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would help to point out to them that in French, the expression "il y a" has nothing to do with anyone who /has/ anything.  In the same way, in English, /there is/ has nothing to do with where anyone is. 
It's an idiom, and that's that!  The question is: "Are there a lot of people in the shop."  The question is formed exactly as any other question in the verb /to be/ in English.  "John and Mary are at home." "Are John and Mary at home?"  "There are a lot people in the shop."   "Are there . . . "